Android global search result query always with same argument Prime Provider
I've followed the official documentation to enable search functionality for my app. I am logging the values received by my Content Provider.
During the query call to the Content Provider, the selectionArgs only contain 'Prime Provider' and do not include the value set in the System Search that triggers my Content Provider.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any information on changes to the search behavior?
Thank you in advance.
As exposed in the details, just followed the documentation regarding the searchable tv apps said link: Searchable TV Apps
Relevant code that I can provide
Searchable associated with my app
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.my.app.search"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.my.app.search/search"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
    android:queryAfterZeroResults="true"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>

Provider in AndroidManifest.xml
       <provider
            android:name=".domain.provider.SearchProvider"
            android:authorities="com.my.app.search"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </provider>


Some logs that I have on my query from the Content Provider
Projection: content://com.my.app.search/search_suggest_query?limit=10
Selection:  ?
Selection Args: prime provider
Selection Args Size: 1


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have done a couple of factory reset of my Android TV box and finally tracked it down to be an issue with "Google TV app for Android TV".
If I uninstall the update, search works as it did previously. I have reported to bug to Google here, please add your findings if you have any.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/370332089
